# Why does my app crash when I download it through 3G?

Tags: google-play-store, wi-fi, 3g

I have developed an application and published it on the Play Store.

My problem is that when I download it from the Play Sore via 3G, the application crashes. However, when I download it via wifi it runs without problem.

Also, after downloading (via wifi), if I disable wifi and enable 3G, the application can be launched and works fine without crash/problem.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems like something you're going to need to debug on your own, at least to some extent. You should be able to "report" the problem to the Play Store when the application crashes - that will give you a stack trace and other useful information. Otherwise I don't think there's enough information to go on. You could also try using logcat at the time of the crash (and also note that this could very well be a programming issue, which would really be off topic for this site, although I guess that's not immediately evident at this point).

Comment: Thanks eldarerathis, I thought its not related to programming. That's why asked it here rather than Stack-overflow. I'll check it in log of eclipse .

Comment: Bad network connection causing corruption?  Very weird behavior.